# learning curve of MVC after enough knowledge of web forms has been acquired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have used web forms to build web applications for almost a year. And I have got to learn the basic life cycle for web forms.
Now the development work gets serious and there is a great chance I will build layering and use mvc instead.
So as the subject goes, what will be the learning curve?

Comment: Do you have any web development experience outside of WebForms?

Answer (score 4):

The learning curve will be quite steep in the beginning, then flattening out probably.

MVC is a very different concept. It embraces the stateless nature of the web, instead of trying to simulate state like ASP.Net Webforms does.

Also there is no designer, just code.

It's easier in my opinion if you grasp the fundamentals, but it's quite different from Webforms.

Comment: Quite different from webforms, but with good basic knowledge of objects models and methods, it's quite easy to catch on to.